# connecting gmail inbox to retool to tracking replies

Tags: gmail-api, hubspot, inbox, retool

i am looking to add a new inbox to my hubspot conversations inbox (the new email added would be a gmail). my team wants to add a new conversation inbox because we will be sending emails off of retool(retool can send emails but does not have an inbox), and creating a new gmail for the replays to go to the hubspot conversation inbox. we want to track these replys to gain more information about our clients and see who is responding and who is not (my company is a tech start up that needs to double check bulding codes, and the emails in the new pending inbox are from the disticts and counties applying the building codes to specific geographical regions). we would be able to access the gmail inbox from gmail inbox as well as the HubSpot inbox. we want to track which clients of ours are sending my company emails and which are not. HubSpot is not able to track, but is there a way for the gmail to be compliant with retool so that way we can see who is replying and "take that client off of the que?"